# Rake Aborted Error when pushing to Heroku (factory_girl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, factory-bot

I am getting this error when trying to push to Heroku:

heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- factory_girl

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'annotate', 
        :git => 'git://github.com/jeremyolliver/annotate_models.git', 
        :branch => 'rake_compatibility'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'spork'
    gem 'factory_girl'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'


# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Here's a similar problem - doesn't look resolved: http://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/heroku_seeking_factory_girl_but_not_finding_her

Answer (score 0):

Something is still trying to load factory_girl, so I'd try running rake db:migrate --trace to see if that provides any helpful info.

Even more to the point, are your specs being compiled into your slug? If so, try including the spec dir in .slugignore. (Basically I'm guessing some unintended side effect is referencing f_g and that seems a likely culprit to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your

```
.slugignore
```

`spec/` and `test/` directories are often ignored.